# xlsxwriter / openpyxl : excel shows the right format but does not apply it until modifying the cell

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

I'm having a problem with xlsxwriter (also with openpyxl) and excel. The Column Format is not being used until I open the workbook, click the cell, and then press enter. The Column has the correct format, but will not display this format until the steps just listed occur. I made sure that my Excel has Automatic Calculation on.
Also, with the same line of code, some columns are well formated, other not.

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
numeric = wb.add_format()
numeric.set_num_format(0x02)  # also tried with 0x44 accounting, same results
... (get the request csv object)
for item in (request):
    col=0
    row +=1
    for field in fields:
      if field:
        ws.write(row, col,item[field])
      col += 1
    if 'inventory' in item:
      if len(item['inventory']) > 0:
        ws.write(row, col,item['inventory'][0]['count'],numeric)
        ws.write(row, col+1,item['inventory'][0]['reorder_point'],numeric)
        ws.write(row, col+2,item['inventory'][0]['restock_level'],numeric)

ws.set_column('Q2:Q'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('R2:R'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('T2:T'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('U2:U'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('V2:V'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('AB2:AB'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('AC2:AC'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)
ws.set_column('AD2:AD'+str(row+1), 10, numeric)

wb.close()
```

In this truncated code, columns Q,U,V,AB,AC and AD does not display correctly, whereas columns R and T does. As I have the same problem with both xlsxwriter and openpyxl, is there a problem with excel? What am I doing wrong?
And last one last clue : if I change the column format in excel, it does nothing except on the recalculated (double cliqued) cells of the column.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the XlsxWriter [`set_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column) method is:

```
set_column(first_col, last_col, width, cell_format, options)
```

Instead of the numeric zero indexed `first_col, last_col` you can use Excel's `A:D` style notation:

```
worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20)
```

However, in your example you are using a 2D range like:

```
ws.set_column('Q2:Q5', 10, numeric)
```

That isn't valid.

Comment: John, shouldn't xlsxwriter be raising exceptions in this case?

Comment: It should, and it will, but this is the first time I've seen this issue.

Comment: Well, TBH `set_column` is pretty clear but users are there to test us! ;-)

Comment: Hello John, thank you for your answer. I corrected my code with :
    ws.set_column('Q:Q', 10, numeric)
and commented the other lines, but the problem still persists. As with the previous lines, the column has the good format but excel is not displaying the cells correctly until I revalidate them. I'm not sure the problem is coming from xlsxwriter as I have the same issue with openpyxl, or by assigning the format during the write process.
The stange fact is that it works for 2 columns on 8...
PS : the "2D" range assignment is working somehow!

Comment: I can send a sample of the generated xlsx. Also the problem is the same on windows and osx versions of excel. I tried with ws.set_column(16,16, 10, numeric), same problem...

Comment: Romain: the output xlsx file won't be helpful. The best thing you could do would be to break this down to a small complete application that demonstrates the issue. Then it should be easy to resolve.